# CADisplayLink not firing often enough

Tags: ios, ios5, core-animation, cadisplaylink

I am using `CADisplayLink` to perform synchronization between sound and animations. The synchronization needs to be really precise and currently running `CADisplayLink` at `frameInterval` of 1 does not call the selector often enough.

Is there a way to increase it's granularity? (`frameInterval` is an integer property so I obviously cannot go below 1)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it raises interesting points, so I'll give my 2 cents.

As stated by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html),

```
A CADisplayLink object is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.
```

Thus you won't be able to get updates more frequent than 60 times per second, the LCD screen display rate. Animations do not have a refresh rate per se, they represent a continuous movement that just happens to be visible every time the screen updates.

I do not have much experience on sound playback, but I'm surprised that the `CADisplayLink` refresh rate is not enough. Does 1/60 of a second really make a difference to the user's ear ?
Maybe the method you are using for sound playback induces some kind of lag ?

Anyway, if you want to sync sound more finely with your animations, I would suggest setting up an `NSTimer` with a repeat interval that suits you, instead of a `CADisplayLink`.

The other things you are gonna need are :

- the `CACurrentMediaTime()` function, which returns the time used by Core Animation at the time it is called
- the `CAAnimation`'s `beginTime` property (which it gets from the `CAMediaTiming` protocol)

Setting `beginTime` as an offset from `CACurrentMediaTime` will allow you to create animations that start at a very precise and controlled time. If you leave it to 0 (the default) when you add an animation to a layer, it will be automatically set to the `CACurrentMediaTime` at the end of the runloop, resulting in less controlled timing.

You can also read `beginTime` from a running `CAAnimation` to know the exact time at which it started, which may not be the exact time you added it the the layer (see above).

Comment: People can be surprisingly sensitive to minor synchronization problems - especially with video and voice (i.e. lip sync).